# How to find the source file for an identifier in Coq

Tags: coq

I was staring at an error for quite a while before I realized that there's both `Rsqrt` and `sqrt` defined somewhere in Coq:

```
Unable to unify "0 < Rsqrt ?M2352 \/ 0 = Rsqrt ?M2352" with "0 < sqrt r12 \/ 0 = sqrt r12".
```

Rather than asking specifically how to find where these two specific items (`Rsqrt` and `sqrt`) are defined, is there a general way to find the `.v` file from the standard library in which a name such as `sqrt` is defined?

BTW, I know `Check` and `Print`. But I need to find the relevant source files or documentation to see what lemmas are available about the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of such a feature, but I think you could use `Locate` (or sometimes `SearchAbout sqrt`) to get the full path of the term, and then easily guess the corresponding `.v` file.

Comment: Do you mean `Locate` rather than `SearchAbout`? `SearchAbout` doesn't give me extended paths.

Comment: You may be right. `SearchAbout` gives path if the module are not imported directly. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Using Emacs + [ProofGeneral](http://proofgeneral.inf.ed.ac.uk/), after following the instructions in the [Installation notes](http://proofgeneral.inf.ed.ac.uk/fileshow.php?file=releases%2FProofGeneral%2Fcoq%2FREADME):

> Install coqtags in a standard place or add /coq to your PATH.
> NB: You may need to change the path to perl at the top of the file.
>
> Generate a TAGS file for the library by running
>
> coqtags `find . -name \*.v -print`
>
> in the root directory of the library, $COQTOP/theories.

you can use `M-.` for going to the `.v` file where the identifier under the cursor was defined and you can use `M-*` to go back.

Answer (score 0):

The emacs addon `company-coq` has this very convenient feature.

https://github.com/cpitclaudel/company-coq